# access class property using a variable name that user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

so basically I have a class that similar to the following but much longer

```
Public Class inventory
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
End Class
```

and in other class I have a list of called order of class inventory
so when I loop over the list I can do as

```
For Each i In orders
        Console.WriteLine(i.name)
Next
```

but I want a variable to be in the spot .
so like

```
Dim rrr As String = Console.ReadLine()
For Each i In orders
     Console.WriteLine(i.rrr)
Next
```

however I get error as rrr is not a member in inventory!
so please any one know how to solve that and be able to access the class from a variable let me know
Thanks

Comment: Maybe a class is not the best way to hold your data, consider using a `Dictionary<string, SomeTypeHere>`

Comment: What do you wanted to do with that variable?  It's not clear what did you mean by you want a variable to spot?

Comment: Sorry I ment the variable name in that would change dynamiclly during the run time.

Comment: Do you mean `dim theOrderISeek = orders.FirstOrDefault(function(o) o.Name.Equals(rrr))`? (or `Contains(rrr)` or `StartsWith(rrr)` or...)

Comment: rrr is a variable name that it's value point to class property. so in the example above the value of rrr is going to be either name or id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer is provided at [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) but it is C#. Following is vb.net translation.

```vb
Public Class inventory
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    'I added a custom constructor to make filling a list easier for me
    Public Sub New(i As Integer, n As String)
        id = i
        name = n
    End Sub
    'add back default constructor
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class

Private orders As New List(Of inventory) From {New inventory(1, "Apples"), New inventory(2, "Oranges"), New inventory(3, "Pears")}

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim rrr As String = "name" 'Console.ReadLine() as if user typed in name
    For Each i In orders
        Console.WriteLine(GetPropertyValue(i, rrr))
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetPropertyValue(src As Object, PropName As String) As Object
    Return src.GetType().GetProperty(PropName).GetValue(src, Nothing)
End Function
```

Output:

> Apples
>
> Oranges
>
> Pears